# iptables put all forwarding rules in prerouting

Tags: linux, security, networking, firewall, iptables

I have a question about security in iptables.

Is it safe to give ACCEPT policy to FORWARD chain? I mean, if packet gets there, it has come through PREROUTING table and in PREROUTING you only change destination ip of packet if you "like it".

all packets that get in FORWARD was matched against one of the rules in PREROUTING right?

Comment: If a packet does not match *any* rules in your `PREROUTING` chain, there is nothing to prevent it from hitting your `FORWARD` chian, unless you set the default `PREROUTING` policy to `DROP`.

Comment: but if it didn't match any rule in PREROUTING chain, so it will keep its destination address and it wiil go to INPUT chain, right? and not FORWARDING. packets that didn't match any rule in PREROUTING go to INPUT and that matched go to FORWARD, am I wrong?

Comment: Packets only go to the `INPUT` chain if their destination address is an address that belongs to a local interface on your host.  Otherwise, they go to the `FORWARD` chain, and if they pass that chain AND the `ip_forward` sysctl is enabled, your system will forward them based on your routing table.

Comment: @larsks- I request you to write the above as an answer. Would look much better and receive my upvote too...

Comment: but if I receive packet, it means it's destination address matches my local interface, and if PREROUTING didn't change it's destination address then it will go only to INPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a packet does not match any rules in your `PREROUTING` chain, there is nothing to prevent it from hitting your `FORWARD` chain, unless you set the default `PREROUTING` policy to DROP.

Packets only go to the `INPUT` chain if their destination address is an address that belongs to a local interface on your host. Otherwise, they go to the `FORWARD` chain, and if they pass that chain AND the `ip_forward` sysctl is enabled, your system will forward them based on your routing table.

Your system may receive packets that are not destined for a local interface. This is how basic routing works: when your system wants to contact, say, Google's dns server at 8.8.8.8, packets are sent to your local default gateway, which receives and routes them even though the destination address is somewhere else entirely.

Your system may explicitly route traffic for physical networks to which it is attached or for containers or virtual machines hosted on the system.  All of these involve your system accepting and forwarding packets that do not match a local interface.